# Crash when trying to sort an array

Tags: objective-c, sorting, crash, nsmutablearray, runtime-error

I am trying to make a highscore page in a space shooter game I made. So, what I do is save the score using this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *highscore = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:_totalSeconds]; 
NSString *choice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userschoice", documentsDirectory];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:choice];
[array addObject: highscore];
[array writeToFile:choice atomically:YES];
```

Where the integer `_totalSeconds` is the user's score. Then, in my `viewDidLoad` function, I put this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *choice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userschoice", documentsDirectory];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:choice];
int _highscoresAmount = [array count]; 
NSNumber *highscore2 = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
NSNumber *highscore2Two = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

int _count = 0;

while (_count<_highscoresAmount){

    for (int i=0; i<_highscoresAmount; i++){

        int j = i+1; 
        highscore2 = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        highscore2Two = [array objectAtIndex:j];
        if (highscore2Two > highscore2){

            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:highscore2Two];
            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:highscore2]; 

        }


}

    _count = _count + 1;

}


for (int i=0; i< _highscoresAmount;i++){

    highscore2 = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *highscore3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", highscore2];
    NSLog(highscore3); 

}
```

The goal of this code is to retrieve the array that I wrote in the file with the path specified in my code. Then, I want to sort the array from highest to lowest.

This builds fine, but when I load the view, the app crashes. What is the problem?

Note: I also tried doing a for loop inside of a for loop using similar code and the same problem occured.

Also, here is the crash log:

unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
kill
quit

Answer (score 1):

I see two major things wrong here. The first is that you're declaring the array as NSMutableArray, but actually making an NSArray. You need to use [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:] to make a mutable array.

The second is that you shouldn't be implementing your own sorting algorithm. Just use the built in sorting methods (-sortUsingComparator: for example)

(edit)

Oh, also, you should use -stringByAppendingPathComponent rather than +stringWithFormat, for constructing paths

Comment: I fixed the first thing with the nsmutable array problem. The app still doesn't work. I tried the stringByAppendingPathComponent, but it gives me the warning that NSString may not respond to stringByAppendingPathComponent.

Comment: Keep in mind I am using xcode 3 so that could be causing some of the problems

Comment: You should post the crash log. Debugging crashes without crash logs is basically impossible.

Comment: I added the crash log. Also, could it be that objectAtIndex:... doesnt recieve an int variable?

Comment: That's not a crash log. That's just a bunch of error messages from the debugger.